# update field to null value when there is no match in related table(s)

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have 2 tables as shown below. I need to update the [incomming letter contractor] field of table [ASBUILT_LIST] with value of [TRANSMITTAL] of table [tblTransmittalls]

I have used the following update query

```
UPDATE ASBUILT_LIST INNER JOIN tblTransmittalls 
   ON ASBUILT_LIST.DOC=tblTransmittalls.DocumentNo 
SET ASBUILT_LIST.[incomming letter   contractor] = [tblTransmittalls]![TRANSMITTAL]
    WHERE  ((tblTransmittalls.PurposeofIssue)="FIN"));
```

Now when there is not any match for [DocumentNo] field (related between 2 tables) I need to update [incomming letter contractor] to `NULL` value.

```
SET ASBUILT_LIST.[incomming letter contractor] = Null
```

and when there is a match it is updated like before:

```
SET ASBUILT_LIST.[incomming letter contractor] = [tblTransmittalls]![TRANSMITTAL]
```

The tables are:

TABLE: ASBUILT_LIST

```
doc                 incomming letter contractor
------------------  ---------------------------
doc-1000            L-0001
doc-2000            L-0002
```

TABLE: tblTransmittalls

```
DocumentNo         TRANSMITTAL      PurposeofIssue
-----------------  ---------------  --------------
DOC-1000           T-0001           FIN
DOC-3000           T-0500           FIN
DOC-4000           T-0600           IFI
DOC-2000           T-0800           IFI
```

I need an updated ASBUILT_LIST table so after running update query it should be like this:

```
doc            incomming letter contractor
-------------  ---------------------------
doc-1000       T-0001   
doc-2000       null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your description correctly, this should be easy with `DLookup()`.

```sql
UPDATE ASBUILT_LIST
SET [incomming letter contractor] = 
    DLookup
        (
            "TRANSMITTAL",
            "tblTransmittalls",
            "DocumentNo = '" & [DOC] & "' AND PurposeofIssue = 'FIN'"
        );
```

Comment: i did it and it works but problem is running update query is very slow, maybe because i have linked tables to other database. when i put the query and tables without link from other database in a separate database speed of running query is normal. but now is very slow.

Comment: Make sure to index `DocumentNo` in `tblTransmittalls`.  I don't know if it would also help to index `PurposeofIssue`; try it with and without an index on that field.